# How to find the port that a service of interest is listening on remotely?

Tags: nmap

There's a remote server on my network that's compromised, with no physical access. The hacker reassigned sshd service to listen on a another port. Is there a way to use nmap to find a port specifically *for* a specified service? (in this case sshd)

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, yes.  You can simply have it scan all ports on the system and enable version numbers.

`nmap <Server> -sV -p 1-65535`

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-09 03:11 CDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00040s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE     VERSION
22/tcp    open  ssh         (protocol 2.0)
80/tcp    open  http        Apache httpd 2.4.7 ((Ubuntu))

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 41.27 seconds
```

You can find more information: [here](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html) and [here](https://nmap.org/book/man-version-detection.html).